# "Invariant unproven" when using method that creates a specific new object in its return statement

Tags: c#, code-contracts

The following simple code will yield an "invariant unproven" warning by the static checker of Code Contracts, although there is no way `_foo` can be `null`. The warning is for the `return` statement inside `UncalledMethod`.

```
public class Node
{
    public Node(string s1, string s2, string s3, string s4, object o,
                string s5)
    {
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    private readonly string _foo;

    public Bar()
    {
        _foo = "foo";
    }

    private object UncalledMethod()
    {
        return new Node(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty,
                        GetNode(), string.Empty);
    }

    private Node GetNode()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public string Foo
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
            return _foo;
        }
    }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void Invariants()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(_foo != null);
    }
}
```

Apart from the fact, that the warning is simply invalid, it only occures in certain specific circumstances. Changing *any* of the following will make the warning go away:

1. Inline `GetNode` so the return statement looks like this:

   ```
   return new Node(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, null,
                   string.Empty);
   ```
2. Remove any of the parameters s1 to s5 from the constructor of `Node`.
3. Change the type of any of the parameters s1 to s5 from the constructor of `Node` to `object`.
4. Use a temporary variable for the result of `GetNode`:

   ```
       var node = GetNode();
       return new Node(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty,
                       node, string.Empty);
   ```
5. Changing the order of the parameters of the constructor of `Node`.
6. Checking the option "Show assumptions" in the code contracts settings pane in the project settings.

**Am I missing something obvious here or is this simply a bug in the static checker?**

---

My settings:

[image]

My output:

```
C:\{path}\Program.cs(20,9): message : CodeContracts: Suggested ensures: Contract.Ensures(this._foo != null);
C:\{path}\Program.cs(41,17): message : CodeContracts: Suggested ensures: Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<System.String>() == this._foo);
C:\{path}\Program.cs(33,13): message : CodeContracts: Suggested ensures: Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ConsoleApplication3.Program+Node>() == null);
C:\{path}\Program.cs(27,13): message : CodeContracts: Suggested ensures: Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<System.Object>() != null);
C:\{path}\Program.cs(55,13): message : CodeContracts: Suggested ensures: Contract.Ensures(Contract.ForAll(0, args.Length, __k__ => args[__k__] != 0));
CodeContracts: ConsoleApplication3: Validated:  92,3%
CodeContracts: ConsoleApplication3: Contract density: 1,81
CodeContracts: ConsoleApplication3: Total methods analyzed 8
CodeContracts: ConsoleApplication3: Methods with 0 warnings 7
CodeContracts: ConsoleApplication3: Total method analysis read from the cache 8
CodeContracts: ConsoleApplication3: Total time 2,522sec. 315ms/method
CodeContracts: ConsoleApplication3: Retained 0 preconditions after filtering
CodeContracts: ConsoleApplication3: Inferred 0 object invariants
CodeContracts: ConsoleApplication3: Retained 0 object invariants after filtering
CodeContracts: ConsoleApplication3: Detected 0 code fixes
CodeContracts: ConsoleApplication3: Proof obligations with a code fix: 0
C:\{path}\Program.cs(27,13): warning : CodeContracts: invariant unproven: _foo != null
C:\{path}\Program.cs(49,13): warning :   + location related to previous warning
C:\windows\system32\ConsoleApplication3.exe(1,1): message : CodeContracts: Checked 13 assertions: 12 correct 1 unknown
CodeContracts: ConsoleApplication3: 
CodeContracts: ConsoleApplication3: Background contract analysis done.
```

Comment: What if you add `Contract.Requires(_foo != null)` in the constructor of `Bar`?

Comment: @JohnWillemse: You can't add a requires for a field in the constructor. Furthermore, it doesn't really make sense as it would mean that `_foo` has to be not null when the constructor is called. That's impossible. Adding a `Contract.Ensures(_foo != null);` to the ctor doesn't fix the warning.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I had a similar issue, but the constructor had a parameter to set `_foo` in that case; I overlooked that here.

Comment: @JohnWillemse: I guess it's a bug. It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I agree. Especially with so many different conditions that can make it go away...weird.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I am using 1.4.51019.0 with VS2010 Ultimate. You might want to upgrade. However, there is something you could do: Make sure that "Show Assumptions" is un-checked in the CC settings. (See point 6 in my list on how to make the warning go away).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Marking it as `Pure` indeed makes the warning go away. But why?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Man, thanks for the hint with `Pure`. I knew it existed, but never even thought about applying it to this problem. It even solves many other problems I am having!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Please have a look at my settings. Make sure yours are the same.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Done. I now get 11 assertions, 11 correct. And 5 suggestions. But no other issues. I'd say it must be a bug of some kind, but not sure where to look. The `Pure` idea was just another thing to eliminate.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Strange. I added my output to the question. Could you please compare it to yours? As you can probably infer from the last suggestion, Program.cs also has a `Main` method.

Comment: I've tried everything I can to match your situation, and I can't find it. I agree it must be a bug somewhere, but it's tricky to work out how to diagnose it further.

Comment: Have you contacted Microsoft Research about this possible bug?

Comment: @RichardCook: [In a way, yes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/8d18d734-f0b0-4204-9490-6d804962b763). But my experience with them is pretty bad. My requests have all been ignored completely.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Sorry for not getting back to you earlier. I am just now preparing a solution that contains all the problems I found and - after upgrading to the now current version "1.4.60221.11" - I can't reproduce it either. Maybe it was some kind of glitch in my installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer a problem with [the latest version](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970).